# What do we do about "Does Anybody do/have X?"?

Tags: discussion

"Does anybody" questions are, to me, a sign of especially poor writing: They ask about mere existence, and then the answer always can be yes, as there will be one experimental setup that did exactly that.

But it is impossible to prove a negative, so such questions stay unanswered or attract poor answers.

So, what should we do about them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Encourage them to rewrite, and if they have the solution, encourage them to write an answer and accept it. The question can be closed by voting so that the author can rewrite the question and add more information (based on some comments of high reputation members and mods), if that doesn't work, the question could be deleted.